# how to set dockerfle run nohup php test.php >myscript.log 2>&1 &

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

How to set dockerfile `run nohup php test.php >myscript.log 2>&1 &`?

my dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.4-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

COPY ./ ./
EXPOSE 8005 80 443
RUN bash -c "nohup php interfacegps.php >myscript.log 2>&1 &"
```

How to set `nohup php interfacegps.php` on dockerfile? My code is not working.

Comment: Ideally, use a program like supervisord to run multiple services in a docker container: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Answer (score 0):

A Docker image never contains a running process, it only has a filesystem and metadata needed to start a container.  When the container starts, it runs whatever its command is, and as soon as that command completes, the container exits.  In a shell context, if you ran a command like the `nohup` command you show and got a shell prompt back, that would be the signal for a Docker container to exit.

You probably want that `php` command to be your image's CMD (the thing that will get run when the container starts).  It must be a foreground process or else the container will exit.  You don't want to try to redirect its logs here or else they will get captured into a file inside the container, which is hard to retrieve.  Finally, you don't need a `bash -c` wrapper here because Docker provides that for you automatically on CMD lines.  That leaves you with just

```sh
CMD php interfacegps.php
```

The easiest way to run this is to use the `docker run -d` option to launch the container in the background, and then use `docker logs` later to review the logs.

```sh
docker run --name interface-gps -d ... myimage
docker logs interface-gps
```

If you really wanted to, you could launch the container in the foreground and capture its output in the same way as you've tried in your RUN line.

```sh
nohup docker run --rm myimage >myscript.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: it's work for me but i have  new problem ,my container run 2 port is 80 and 8005 when i put code "CMD php interfacegps.php"(websocket run port 8005) in docker file , port 80 not working but if i not put code "CMD php interfacegps.php" port 80 is working

Comment: The same thing happens to me.